# Controllers in two level subdirectory

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any hack to provide two level sub directory controllers support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll supply with extending the controller.

Copy [this](http://codepad.org/LyTh0bKK) code into your CI application library folder (the default is /system/application/libraries), and name it as MY_Router.php

Comment: You just save my life. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not without modifying the core.
Although, I'm not sure as why you would need to?

I would suggest that you focus on routes instead:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

By having one level subfolders in system/application/controllers you could with easy, by adding an URI route, make system/application/controllers/my_sub_level accessable trough
http://example.com/myfirstlevel/mysecondlevel/mythirdlevel/my_sub_level by adding this route:

```
$route['myfirstlevel/mysecondlevel/mythirdlevel/my_sub_level/:any'] = "my_sub_level/welcome";
```

Comment: I know about routes but I need file structure to looks like controllers/frontend/misc/controller.php Do you know any core hacks  ?